# How can or should one use OnAcceleratedPaint for WPF

Tags: cefsharp, chromium-embedded

While searching for discussions on Cef/CefSharp's WPF performance I have stumbled on the new (I think as of last update 71.0) [CefSharp API - OnAcceleratedPaint](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/71.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_Wpf_ChromiumWebBrowser_OnAcceleratedPaint.htm)

Am I understanding things correctly that for WPF, Cef first renders the HTML "off screen" and then from here the WPF window element is created with the help of Direct3D9?

**Edited / Updated Question**
Does Cef now offer the opportunity of rendering the whole HTML with D3D10/11? or is this new method meant only to render for example video elements.

Currently the only example on point is [shown in this example](https://github.com/daktronics/cef-mixer) which use d3d11 in unmanaged code.

Looking at these references it seems possible to use D3D10/11 with WPF [Direct3D 10/11 & Direct2D in WPF](http://jmorrill.hjtcentral.com/Home/tabid/428/EntryId/437/Direct3D-10-11-Direct2D-in-WPF.aspx) and here with [Introduction to D3DImage](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28526/Introduction-to-D3DImage)

In the first referenced link I see the answer for WPF is;

> So how do we render D3D10/11 and D2D into WPF w/o airspace issues?  We only have a D3DImage class that supports Direct3D9.  Well the fine people of the WPF team informed me that a IDirect3DDevice9Ex, which is the recommended device to use with D3DImage in Vista/7, supports sharing resources between devices (and processes too if you care).  We can create a shared render target on Direct3D10/11, then pull it in via an intermediate IDirect3DDevice9Ex device.  No copying required!  This resource we pull into 9Ex, can then be sent to the D3DImage for high performance rendering.

However looking at [this thread here](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2527) in combination with the [the discussion here](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/2559/cefclientexe-shared-texture-enabled-off) the current version is not working properly anyway and for people using CefSharp we should wait for Cef (upstream) to work out the kinks first.

What exactly does amaitland mean in the thread by?

> `Chrome` changes will break `OnAcceleratedPaint` in newer version of `CEF`

Comment: You could try asking the OP of https://github.com/daktronics/cef-mixer/issues/17 for some advice

Comment: I did not see the closed issues. Good idea. I was under the impression, however from a number CefSharp issues (that were questions) that GitHub issues are for issues and places like here are for questions.

Comment: If your creating an issue that your app won't start because you haven't installed VC++ then stackoverflow is a much better place to ask, there's a whole community to help moderate and answer  if your working on providing an example of a new feature that you'll contribute back to the community then that's very different.